# How to display hierarchical "NESTED SET" data with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to display nested MySQL data using php. I've managed to set aside all the "leaf nodes" but then I got stucked. I need to display a whole tree and all of it's element's relations. 
Here's the table

```
category_id, name, lft, rgt
1 Saws 1 12
2 Chainsaws 2 7
3 Red 3 4
4 Yellow 5 6
5 Circular saws 8 9
6 Other saws 10 11
```

Here is code:

```
$query = 'SELECT node.name, node.lft, node.rgt
    FROM item_cats AS node,
        item_cats AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND parent.name = "' . SAWS . '"
    ORDER BY node.lft';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['rgt'] == $row['lft']+1) {
        echo '==>';
    }
    echo $row['lft'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['rgt'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

And this is what i get:

```
1Saws12
2Chainsaws7
==>3Red4
==>5Yellow6
==>8Circular saws9
==>10Other saws11
```

Comment: @AdamPlocher [Nested Set Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), scroll down to the 'The Nested Set Model' heading, the first bit's about a different technique

Comment: Ahh interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the link Stu showed me, the tutorial shows this query for determining depth:

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft
```

So something like this should work:

```
<?PHP
$query = 'SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
    FROM nested_category AS node,
            nested_category AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.name
    ORDER BY node.lft';

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row['depth']; $i++) {
        echo '==>';
    }

    echo $row['name'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

This should output:

```
Saws
==>Chainsaws
==>==>Red
==>==>Yellow
==>Circular Saws
==>Other Saws
```

Comment: Ahh shoot, sorry I just found a bug... that `where parent.name="saws"` is causing the depth to return 0... Let me try to fix it.

Comment: Oh awesome.  You're welcome.  I'm going to change my answer so it doesn't have that `parent.name` condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP
$query = '
    select if(
        count(a.name) - 1 = 0, 
        a.name, 
        concat(repeat('   ', count(a.name) - 2), '+--', b.name)
    )name
    from nested_category b, nested_category a
    where node.lft between a.lft and a.rgt
    group by b.name
    order by b.lft';

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) echo "{$row['name']}<br>";
?>
```

Should do sth like:

```
Saws
+--Chainsaws
   +--Red
   +--Yellow
+--Circular Saws
+--Other Saws
```