# get all child id of super parent in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with below data.

```
id|child
1|2
1|3
1|4
2|6
2|7
3|9
6|10
6|11
17|18
19|20
18|19
```

I need to fetch the data like below. i.e super-parent to all child relationship for a id (say here 1 and 19).

Here I have select all child's recursively of super parent id "1"

```
id|all_child_id
1|2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11
```

Here I want to select all child's of super parent id '17'.

```
id|all_child_id
17|18,19,20
```

I am not aware how to write recursive queries in sql.

Please do not ask me to create intermediate table.

Comment: "I am not aware how to write recursive queries in sql." - Step 1: Find a tutorial or book to learn it. Step 2: Try applying to your problem. Step 3: If you have a specific issue when trying, post it here.

Comment: There are some superb tutorials/articles on recursion in MySQL

Comment: the popular one: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar-- I have already gone through the article you have provided. But i could not find solution for my problem.I need N level recursion.

Comment: @ shree.pat18- Can you please provide where I can get N level recursion for "MYSQL"

Comment: @shree.pat18: Step 0: use a different DBMS than MySQL. MySQL does not support recursive queries

Comment: "*I am not aware how to write recursive queries in sql*" - you can't in MySQL (and you have already been told that when you asked the exact same question 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647606)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are of course right. I was thinking along the lines of this: http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html

Comment: @All- I have never posted any question without some research. If any one of you are getting the proper answer from any of the reference material you have shared, then please let me know too.. I hope it will  improve me.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here to circumvent recursive queries in MySQL is called "Nested Set Model" (see chapter "The Nested Set Model" [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for example)

You can find an implementation example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471605/how-to-display-hierarchical-nested-set-data-with-php).

I was looking for better tutorial pages but couldn't find any so far. But I'm sure they exist. So if anyone has better links, pls provide them as a comment here. Thanks!

EDIT: [This](http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/) was the tutorial I was looking for earlier, but sadly its written in german. Maybe the SQL snippets still help you if you decide to and are able to change your data model to fit into a nested set.

Answer (score 0):

It Will work for getting the all the child of your parent

```
   declare @parent_id as int;
    set @parent_id =  1;

    WITH RecursiveTable (SR_NO, parent_id,name, Level)
    AS
    (    
        SELECT      MaintTab.SR_NO, 
                    MaintTab.parent_id, 
                    MaintTab.name,
                    0 AS Level
        FROM Product_Master_Final AS MaintTab
        WHERE parent_id = @parent_id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  MaintTab.SR_NO, 
                    MaintTab.parent_id, 
                    MaintTab.name ,
                    LEVEL + 1
        FROM Product_Master_Final AS MaintTab
            INNER JOIN RecursiveTable Rtab ON
            MaintTab.parent_id = Rtab.SR_NO
    )
    SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable
```

Comment: what are these things? --- SR_NO,name, Level

Comment: it's just data if you want to carry with the tables if you don't want to then please remove it. SR_NO is child and parent_id is parent id. Level shows the level if the hierarchy. you can try it visa-verse for parent_id and sr_no.

Comment: I think with Recursiable is not supported by mysql.

Comment: I think this won't work for N level recursion, right?

Comment: This will help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/generating-depth-based-tree-from-hierarchical-data-in-mysql-no-ctes/5291159#5291159